# How to sort a column with positive and negative numbers in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am having one excel book with few data. One of the columns in the data set contains both the negative and positive values in a percentage format. When I try to sort using excel option, it is not recognising the positive and negative numbers rather it is sorting as below.

Following is the image in which data is in DESCENDING order as per excel sort.

[image]

Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Is the A1 data entered as -0.028 or differently?

Comment: What is actually in those cells?  How is the plus sign being displayed?

Comment: it looks like your number may actually be text values, and it is sorting them as it would text values

Comment: Did you check if the values contain Space?

Comment: The basic issue is that how you have entered data since if you type `+1.5%`, excel will convert into `1.5` and, reason is that +ve values doesn't needs any sign since Negative does need. If you write `1.6%` & `0.2`%` and apply Custom Format to both and add `+` , `-` the Excel will consider both as Positive Numbers. Better make it clear !!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the way it has sorted things it appears that the data is very likely text. In Cell B1 enter the formula A1*1. Copy it down to B13 then copy and paste values over the information in column A. Then delete column B.

Hopefully, that will help.